# Content.IE5 in sysWOW64 directory keeps growing

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem at the moment where the content.ie5 directory in the Temporary Internet Files folder in \Windows\syswow64 is just growing by many GB per day (9GB overnight) I am able to manually delete the contents with powershell in administrator mode, but it just grows back straight away.

I have set the internet settings to only allow 8mb of diskspace and I have changed the location of Temporary Internet Files to my E:\ drive. Windows has created the hiddent temp folder but the size is ignored and there is another hidden folder in SysWOW64

I have run a antivirus scan (with MS Security Essentials) and a rootkit scan and nada.

What the hell is doing this ?

(I am on Windows 7 with IE11, IE11 is virtually never used, I use Chrome for browsing)

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) or if you [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)? Did you try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to track down what's creating the temporary files in first place?

Comment: Booted several times...didn't try safe mode as obviously that wont download to the dir with no network connection. Not sure if its just that I don't know how to use PE properly, but I couldn't see what process was writing to that dir....I couldn't see the handle to the directory at all...maybe because its super hidden ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant safe mode *with networking*. Also, while Process Explorer might help, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is actually better suited for the job - provided you [use the right filters](http://blogs.technet.com/b/appv/archive/2008/01/24/process-monitor-hands-on-labs-and-examples.aspx).

Comment: I'm also seeing this, however it looks like the files have nothing to do with Internet Explorer, or the Internet.  It's all logs for the .Net Assembly Binder.

Comment: @ppittle yep, that's what it turned out to be.

Comment: @TimJarvis - Did you figure out why it was happening or more important how to prevent these files from being generated?  I know I can delete them, but it's annoying to have to repeatedly delete these folders.

Comment: @ppittle Yes, I just turned fusion logging off... here is a link to a handy powershell script to do that... http://poshcode.org/2107